# Checkbox disabling an input

Tags: javascript, checkbox

I want to make it so when the user clicks the checkbox , the player Two input goes disabled. My problem is that the input remains disabled in both cases, doesn't matter if checkbox is checked or not.

```js
const Initialization = (function() {
  p1 = '';
  p2 = '';

  const playerOne = document.querySelector('#player1')
  const playerTwo = document.querySelector('#player2')
  const checkAI = document.querySelector('#computer')
  const startButton = document.querySelector('#start')

  startButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
    p1 = Player(playerOne.value)
    p2 = Player(playerTwo.value)
  })

  if (checkAI.checked = true) {
    playerTwo.disabled = true;
  } else {
    playerTwo.disabled = false;
  }

  return {
    p1,
    p2,

  }
})();
```

```html
<label>Computer: <input type="checkbox" id="computer"></label><br/>
<input type="text" id="player1"><br/>
<input type="text" id="player2"><br/>
<input type="button" id="start" value="Start" />
```

Comment: Please post `HTML` too and edit all question with a snippet (use tool `[<>]`)

Comment: You need to add a listener to the checkbox to update the disabled state on `change`

Comment: `checkAI.checked = true` is assignment, use `checkAI.checked === true` or simply `checkAI.checked`

Answer (score 1):

worked by adding an eventListener to the checkbox.

```
    checkAI.addEventListener('click',()=>{
        if(checkAI.checked){
          playerTwo.disabled = true;
        }else{
          playerTwo.disabled = false;
        }
      })
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to react on checkbox change you need to add event listener on this input. For example `onclick` or `onchange`. Take care to use comparaison operator in your `if` test `checkAI.checked === true`. You can find a JSFiddle
[Event on checkbox input](https://jsfiddle.net/sanwoyf1/10/)

Answer (score 0):

You need an event handler and to test equality using `==` or `===`

Here is a simpler version

```js
const Initialization = function() {
  const Player = str => console.log(str);
  const playerOne = document.querySelector('#player1')
  const playerTwo = document.querySelector('#player2')
  const checkAI = document.querySelector('#computer')
  const startButton = document.querySelector('#start')


  let p1 = '';
  let p2 = '';
  startButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
    p1 = Player(playerOne.value)
    p2 = Player(playerTwo.value || "computer")
  });
  checkAI.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    const chk = e.target.checked;
    playerTwo.disabled = chk;
    if (chk) playerTwo.value="";
  })  
};
Initialization()
```

```html
<label>Computer: <input type="checkbox" id="computer"></label><br/>
<input type="text" id="player1"><br/>
<input type="text" id="player2"><br/>
<input type="button" id="start" value="Start" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this reactiveness by listening for the [change event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/change_event) on the checkbox element and updating the input state accordingly:

```js
const Initialization = (function() {
  p1 = '';
  p2 = '';

  const playerOne = document.querySelector('#player1')
  const playerTwo = document.querySelector('#player2')
  const checkAI = document.querySelector('#computer')
  const startButton = document.querySelector('#start')

  startButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
    p1 = Player(playerOne.value)
    p2 = Player(playerTwo.value)
  })

  // listen for change event on checkbox
  checkAI.addEventListener('change', () => {
    // set playerTwo input to current checkbox state
    playerTwo.disabled = checkAI.checked
  })

  return {
    p1,
    p2,
  }
})();
```

```html
<label>Computer: <input type="checkbox" id="computer"></label><br/>
<input type="text" id="player1"><br/>
<input type="text" id="player2"><br/>
<input type="button" id="start" value="Start" />
```